# ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I've been trying to install numpy onto my python set-up on a Galileo Board for about a week now, and this is the latest error I'm getting:

(verbose output)

```
error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC 
-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 
-Ibuild/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath 
-Ibuild/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/include/numpy
-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath 
-Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort 
-I/home/root/python3.6/include/python3.6m -Ibuild/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/common 
-Ibuild/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c
-o build/temp.linux-i586-3.6/build/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-i586-3.6/build/src.linux-i586-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 4


Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Additional Details:

- python version: 3.6
- pip: 20.2.2
- wheel: 0.35.1

Comment: `pip install numpy --no-use-pep517`?

Comment: No good, I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython', let's see if installing it will work

Comment: It raised a "LegacyInstallFailure" immediately after attempting to setup.py. Where to from here?

Comment: Someone really doesn't want me to set that --no-use-pep517 flag:
Failed to build numpy
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for numpy which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.